# Am I using the "ln" and "unlink" commands correctly?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, directory, symbolic-link, hard-link

I have several JavaScript projects that use the same set of utility scripts.

Today after copying (`cp`) the library folder for the dozenth time, I did some research I found the `ln` && `unlink` commands.

I used `ln` to create a symbolic link to the `lib` folder, like this:

```
ln -s -t ~/Development/Web/Project.js ~/Development/Libraries/Main.js/lib
```

From what I understand, the previous command:

1. creates a **symbolic** link using `-s`
2. creates a link to the `lib` folder from `~/Development/Libraries/Main.js` in the `~/Development/Web/Project.js` folder
3. when I deleting the link using `unlink ~/Development/Web/Project.js/lib` it doesn't affect (modify) the `lib` folder in the `Main.js` folder
4. a symbolic link is a (non mutable) pointer to the the target inode
5. a hard link which creates a new with a link to the target's inode
6. you can also link/unlink files using the same commands

Are my assumptions correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your assumptions appears correct to me, only the 4th point is incorrect.
A symbolic link is a path to the target, not  a pointer to the inode of the target,
that's why symbolink links work across file systems.

To demonstrate how the unlink command works I created a few files and a directory
in which I will create the links:

```
~$ touch test
~$ touch test1
~$ mkdir dir
```

Now I create a symbolic link to `test` and a hard link to `test1`

```
~$ ln -s -t dir test
~$ ln -t dir test1
~$ ls -l dir
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 4 Jul 23 19:21 test -> test
-rw-rw-r-- 2 user user 0 Jul 23 19:22 test1
~$ ls -l test1
-rw-rw-r-- 2 user user 0 Jul 23 19:20 test1
```

You can see that the hard link `dir/test1` has a hardlink-count of `2`, also the target `test1` has a has a hardlink-count of `2`.

Now I remove the symbolic link `dir/test`

```
~$ unlink dir/test
~$ ls -l dir
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 2 user user 0 Jul 23 19:22 test1
~$ ls -l test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Jul 23 19:20 test
```

We see that the link is removed, but the original file `test` still exists.

Now I remove the hard link `dir/test1`:

```
~$ unlink dir/test1
~$ ls -l test1
~$ ls -l dir
 total 0
~$ ls -l test1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Jul 23 19:20 test1
```

And again we see that the link is removed, but the original file `test1` still exists, but its hardlink-count is now `1`.

I never used the `unlink`-command, you will achieve the same result with the `rm`-command.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and putting in the effort to explain this to me, I appreciate it.